# AWS SAM CLI does not find docker

Tags: docker, macos, apple-m1, aws-sam

Trying to run commands `sam build --use-container` and `sam local start-api`, both return errors about docker being unreachable, although it is running and active. I am using iMac with M1 processor, this could be the issue, but I could not find anyone else having this issue specifically on Apple Silicon.

The directory of the project is under /Users/, thus it is by default included in docker shared directories.

The output of `docker info`:

```
Client:
 Context:    desktop-linux
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc., v0.9.1)
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc., v2.12.0)
  dev: Docker Dev Environments (Docker Inc., v0.0.3)
  extension: Manages Docker extensions (Docker Inc., v0.2.13)
  sbom: View the packaged-based Software Bill Of Materials (SBOM) for an image (Anchore Inc., 0.6.0)
  scan: Docker Scan (Docker Inc., v0.21.0)

Server:
 Containers: 1
  Running: 1
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 1
 Server Version: 20.10.20
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Cgroup Version: 2
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 9cd3357b7fd7218e4aec3eae239db1f68a5a6ec6
 runc version: v1.1.4-0-g5fd4c4d
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
  cgroupns
 Kernel Version: 5.15.49-linuxkit
 Operating System: Docker Desktop
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: aarch64
 CPUs: 4
 Total Memory: 3.84GiB
 Name: docker-desktop
 ID: 5UH7:HBEP:RUEN:WDIA:O57J:K5I2:IPTO:UW5A:W7D4:7IJD:IZJJ:4QRB
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 HTTP Proxy: http.docker.internal:3128
 HTTPS Proxy: http.docker.internal:3128
 No Proxy: hubproxy.docker.internal
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  hubproxy.docker.internal:5000
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

SAM version:

```
{
  "version": "1.60.0"
}
```

Below is the debug output of the `sam local start-api` command.

```
2022-10-21 21:46:53,547 | Telemetry endpoint configured to be https://aws-serverless-tools-telemetry.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/metrics
2022-10-21 21:46:53,547 | Using config file: samconfig.toml, config environment: default
2022-10-21 21:46:53,547 | Expand command line arguments to:
2022-10-21 21:46:53,547 | --template_file=/Users/ignas/Projects/cv-de-task/template.yaml --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3000 --static_dir=public --layer_cache_basedir=/Users/ignas/.aws-sam/layers-pkg --container_host=localhost --container_host_interface=127.0.0.1 
2022-10-21 21:46:53,605 | local start-api command is called
2022-10-21 21:46:53,608 | No Parameters detected in the template
2022-10-21 21:46:53,617 | There is no customer defined id or cdk path defined for resource HelloWorldFunction, so we will use the resource logical id as the resource id
2022-10-21 21:46:53,617 | There is no customer defined id or cdk path defined for resource ServerlessRestApi, so we will use the resource logical id as the resource id
2022-10-21 21:46:53,618 | 0 stacks found in the template
2022-10-21 21:46:53,618 | No Parameters detected in the template
2022-10-21 21:46:53,624 | There is no customer defined id or cdk path defined for resource HelloWorldFunction, so we will use the resource logical id as the resource id
2022-10-21 21:46:53,624 | There is no customer defined id or cdk path defined for resource ServerlessRestApi, so we will use the resource logical id as the resource id
2022-10-21 21:46:53,624 | 2 resources found in the stack 
2022-10-21 21:46:53,624 | Found Serverless function with name='HelloWorldFunction' and CodeUri='hello_world/'
2022-10-21 21:46:53,624 | --base-dir is not presented, adjusting uri hello_world/ relative to /Users/ignas/Projects/cv-de-task/template.yaml
2022-10-21 21:46:53,626 | Docker is not reachable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.60.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.60.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 398, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.15/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1256, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.15/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1302, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.15/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1251, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.15/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1011, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.15/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 951, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.60.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 43, in connect
    sock.connect(self.unix_socket)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.60.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.60.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 787, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.60.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 550, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.60.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 769, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.60.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.60.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 398, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.15/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1256, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.15/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1302, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.15/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1251, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.15/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1011, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.15/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 951, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.60.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 43, in connect
    sock.connect(self.unix_socket)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.60.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/local/docker/utils.py", line 91, in is_docker_reachable
    docker_client.ping()
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.60.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/client.py", line 187, in ping
    return self.api.ping(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.60.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/api/daemon.py", line 166, in ping
    return self._result(self._get(self._url('/_ping'))) == 'OK'
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.60.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in inner
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.60.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 230, in _get
    return self.get(url, **self._set_request_timeout(kwargs))
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.60.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 555, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.60.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.60.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.60.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 498, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))
2022-10-21 21:46:53,663 | Sending Telemetry: {'metrics': [{'commandRun': {'requestId': 'a2779315-7fbf-4fde-8283-bddfa27b32f7', 'installationId': '82f40a94-c925-4ca9-9100-5436acfc489d', 'sessionId': '2252259d-ee1f-4881-84a1-90b4a884b272', 'executionEnvironment': 'CLI', 'ci': False, 'pyversion': '3.8.15', 'samcliVersion': '1.60.0', 'awsProfileProvided': False, 'debugFlagProvided': True, 'region': '', 'commandName': 'sam local start-api', 'metricSpecificAttributes': {'projectType': 'CFN', 'gitOrigin': None, 'projectName': 'd067e474cfd36d5302b727ce111f9a64cd5415b562d46dc558bdc05173eea29b', 'initialCommit': None}, 'duration': 115, 'exitReason': 'DockerIsNotReachableException', 'exitCode': 1}}]}
2022-10-21 21:46:54,376 | HTTPSConnectionPool(host='aws-serverless-tools-telemetry.us-west-2.amazonaws.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=0.1)
Error: Running AWS SAM projects locally requires Docker. Have you got it installed and running?
```

Comment: Run `docker info` in your terminal and share the output. If you get "_This error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running_", it's probably because something's wrong with Docker engine, as it's not up and running.

Comment: @msamsami I've added additional info to the question

Comment: I'm encountering the same issue, also on an M1 Mac. Please update if you find a solution!

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause of the errors you are getting is that you are using an incompatible version of Docker for your iMac with M1 processor. The **sam** commands you are trying to run require Docker to build and run your serverless application locally, but they may not work well with the Docker version you have installed.

### Explanation

According to the official documentation of AWS SAM CLI, the **sam build --use-container** command builds your application inside a Docker container that mimics the Lambda execution environment. The **sam local start-api** command runs your application locally by using a Docker network. Both of these commands depend on Docker to function properly.

However, not all versions of Docker are compatible with the iMac M1 processor, which uses a different architecture than the Intel-based Macs. The M1 processor uses the ARM64 architecture, which is more efficient and powerful, but also requires different binaries and libraries than the x86_64 architecture used by Intel.

As of now, Docker has released a preview version of Docker Desktop for Mac with Apple Silicon support, which you can download from [here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/apple-silicon/). This version is still experimental and may have some bugs or limitations, but it should allow you to run the **sam** commands without errors. Alternatively, you can try to use a different tool to run your serverless application locally, such as [LocalStack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack), which does not rely on Docker.

Answer (score 1):

My company development has been on hold due to this issue for over a week now. I can confirm that the [latest patch 4.13.1](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/release-notes/) addresses the issue.

Once updated to 4.13.1, be sure to restart docker fully.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that you need to enable the advanced option `Allow the default Docker socket to be used (requires password)`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Docker Desktop fixed this issue with their latest [release](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/release-notes/#docker-desktop-4131):

> Added back the /var/run/docker.sock symlink on Mac by default, to increase compatibility with tooling like tilt and docker-py. Fixes docker/for-mac#6529.

Make sure your Docker Desktop is updated.